# Convert YYDDD to YY/MM/DD

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a way to convert a date in format YYDDD to YY/MM/DD.

i.e. 12212 becomes 12/07/30.

An example in php can be found at http://www.longpelaexpertise.com.au/toolsJulian.php and you can find a DDD calendar at http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html

I'd appreciate any guidance both with and without perl modules.

Thanks!

**edit:** I'm not looking for a way to convert php2perl or anything like that. I'm simply looking for a way to convert YYDDD to YY/MM/DD using perl. I would prefer a way without using any additional perl modules however if that is the only way to do it, then I'll welcome examples using perl modules.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: So you're looking for a `php2perl` tool??

Comment: The standard for date manipulation these days is the DateTime series of modules.  http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime

Comment: @AndyLester: If it were the *"standard for date manipulation"* it would be in core Perl, however it is not. `Time::Piece`, however, is, but unfortunately has problems with day-of-year parsing; see my answer.

Comment: @Borodin Just because something is in core does not mean it is especially good, recommended, modern, or *standard*. It's just there to bootstrap the installation of perl and other CPAN modules (or for historical reasons).

Comment: @Borodin: "If it were the 'standard for date manipulation' it would be in core Perl" is definitely not the case.

Comment: While DateTime has become something of a 'standard', it also carries with it some amount of bloat. For something this basic, I'd probably go with Time::Piece (and the Time::Piece %j issue is being fixed, w/fix available on RT, you're welcome).

Comment: The `Time::Piece` module has been fixed. You can now use `Time::Piece` with version 1.23 of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short and sweet way to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days);

my $dt = '12212';

my $startYr = 2000 + substr($dt, 0, 2);
my $daysToAdd = substr($dt, 2) - 1;
my ($newYr, $newMo, $newDay) = Add_Delta_Days($startYr, 1, 1, $daysToAdd);

printf("%02d/%02d/%02d\n", $newYr % 100, $newMo, $newDay);
```

Comment: You need a two-digit year separated by slashes, so `printf("%02d/%02d/%02d\n", $newYr % 100, $newMo, $newDay);`

Comment: I don't know why you got a -1. In many ways I think this is the best of the solutions. +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

The nicest way would be to use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) to parse the date and reformat it, like this

```
Time::Piece->strptime('12212', '%y%j')->strftime('%y/%m/%d')
```

unfortunately however, the module doesn't accept `%j` (day of year) in its `strptime` format (although it is fine in `strftime`).

The second best option is `strftime` from the [`POSIX`](https://metacpan.org/module/POSIX) module. The string has to be split into year and day first, and the day of year is zero-based so one must be subtracted, but then the conversion is straightforward. It is probably best packaged as a subroutine, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX 'strftime';

sub yj2ymd {
  my ($year, $yday) = $_[0] =~ /(\d\d)(\d\d\d)/;
  strftime('%y/%m/%d', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2000+$year, 0, $yday-1);
}

print yj2ymd('12212');
```

**output**

```
12/07/30
```

You will have to do something fancier with the year if you expect any dates from last century.

Comment: For some reason, I get `11/12/31` as output from your code snippet, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @amon: How bizarre. Is your POSIX up to date? I have 1.30. That's the value you get with the last two parameters removed from `strftime`.

Comment: `POSIX->VERSION` says `1.32`, perl is v18.1. Seems to be a bug: with an older perl everything works. Investigating. Maybe I messed up some compilation flags.

Comment: @amon: [The docs](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod#FUNCTIONS) imply that the behaviour of `strftime` is dependent on the underlying system function. Perhaps that is the difference: I am on Windows whereas you clearly are not.

Comment: Time::Piece and %j works for me. Probably depends on version.

Comment: After a little research, I find that it did work in 1.13, and broke somewhere along the way to 1.20.

Comment: @runrig: What platform as you running on? I looked at this a couple years ago. I remember that somewhere along the line `Time::Piece` was changed from having its own code for `strftime` to using the native library. I can see why this was thought to be a good idea, but it does make the module behave differently across platforms.

Comment: @Scott: I hesitate to recommend `POSIX` as it is a huge monolith of a module. However I believe it does om-demand loading of functions so it's not as bad as it might be.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the heads up - answer modified accordingly.

Comment: @Scott - It will be fixed in a future release of Time::Piece.

Comment: @Scott - Or you can [fix it yourself](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=88211)

Comment: Time::Piece version 1.23 fixes the issue with Time::Piece and Julian dates. At least on the Mac. I haven't tested this on the PC or Linux yet.

Comment: Just finished testing on Windows and Linux. Time::Piece now works.

Comment: @DavidW. Thanks David - I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) simply because it comes with Perl since, I believe revision 5.10. You'll find dozens of date/time modules and everyone has their favorites, but with `Time::Piece` becoming part of the official distribution, it's time to switch to that.

To use Time::Piece, you need to know about [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) (**STR**ing **P**arse **TIME**) and [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) (**STR**ing **F**ormat **TIME**) both which uses `%x` letter formats to represent certain aspects of your time string. The reason is that `Time::Piece` uses the same `%x` format characters to both convert your time string to a *time object* and sometimes to format that *time object* into your string.

From `strftime`'s manpage:

> **%j**
>
> The day of the year as a decimal number (range 001 to 366).

And:

> %y
>
> The year as a decimal number without a century (range 00 to 99).

Now to convert your date:

```
use Time::Piece;

my $old_time = "12212";   #YYddd
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime( $old_time, "%y%j" );
my $new_time = $time->ymd("/"); Now in YY/MM/DD format
```

---

## Whoops

> Hang on — strptime does not grok %j. This will give the wrong answer.

I didn't test this because I have used Time::Piece so often that I can do it in my sleep. I never used `%j` before in `Time::Piece`. The perldoc mentions nothing about `%j` not working, and I don't get any sort of error. That's not nice.

New strategy. I can parse the `YYddd` string into year and days. Then, I can get the **beginning** of the year as `01/01/$year`. After that, I can take the days, and add it to the year. However, to do this correctly, I need a constant from [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $old_date = "12212";
$old_date =~ /(..)(.*)/;
my $year = $1;
my $days = $2;

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime("01/01/$year", "%m/%d/%y");
$time += ( ( $days - 1 ) * ONE_DAY);  #01/01/$year is day 1 and not 0

say  $time->strftime("%y/%m/%d");
```

That gives `12/07/30` as the answer.

---

## Announcement

The owner of the `Time::Piece` module fixed the error in the module. Version 1.23 now works:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

use Time::Piece;

my $old_time = "12212";   #YYddd
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime( $old_time, "%y%j" );
my $new_time = $time->ymd("/"); #Now in YY/MM/DD format
say "Version: $Time::Piece::VERSION";
say $new_time;
```

This prints out:

```
Version: 1.23
2012/07/30
```

Comment: Hang on — strptime does not grok `%j`.  This will give the wrong answer.

Comment: I assume you haven't tried this? First of all `strptime` is broken and won't accept `%j`, secondly, `ymd` returns the *full* four-digit year, when what is wanted is `%y/%m/%d`.

Comment: As I suspected, the result is `2012/01/01`, which isn't right at all.

Comment: @pilcrow I didn't know that `Time::Piece` didn't grok `%j`. Nothing in the Perldoc, and it returns a valid time object. To me, this is a major bug. Redid my answer taking this into account. See above.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of strptime/strftime. As you said yourself, the original answer you provided was inaccurate, however, the second attempt provides the correct answer - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for fixing the `%j` business.  I wasn't able to remove my +1 on your original answer, but I would have put it right back after the update, anyway. :)

Comment: @pilcrow Taking a look in the `Time::Piece` module to see what's going on. It depends upon a `_strptime` subroutine that's not defined in the Perl portion of the module, nor in any included Perl module. Must be from the `auto/Time/Piece` C code. I'm going to report this as a bug.

Comment: IMO there is a lot that could be done with `Time::Piece` to make it more useful. There *really* should be an `add_days` to go with the `add_months` and `add_years`, especially as adding a day is a different thing from adding 86,400 seconds. It would also be nice to have other constructors. At present you can only set the object to "now" or a copy of another `Time::Piece` object unless you use `strptime`. It needs some setter methods to go with its many getters, and adding constants like `ONE_DAY` shouldn't necessitate using another module.

Comment: @Borodin I use to use `Date::Calc` if was available because that's what I saw most people use. Sometimes I used `Data::Manip` if that's what other people were using. I switched to `Time::Piece` because it's been included since Perl 5.10. I hope this means that it has been the well tested and bugs are quickly squashed. Otherwise, I don't know why this and not other date/time modules were chosen. But, including it makes it the standard which everyone in our group will use.